# Hosting a Pytorch Environment on Azure with Jupyter Notebooks usng Active Directory Authentication

Tags: python, azure, jupyter, pytorch

I am looking for a way for non-technical employees within my company to access a Jupyter Notebook hosted on a python environment (with pytorch) hosted on Azure, with active directory authentication. I do not want to use the Azure Machine Learning tools. The goal is to setup an Azure VM with the Jupyter Notebook script along with the necessary dataset/files that the script needs to access existing in the VM's resources. A simple use case would be a user clicks a link directing them to Active Directory authentication, then once logged in, takes them directly to the Jupyter notebook containing a single script that the user can execute, but not edit. The VM also needs to have dependencies such as Pytorch and Scikit-learn. Does anybody know a possible solution to this?

I would use notebooks.azure.com, however there is no current functionality for privately sharing notebooks.